# Calculate Present value for groups with different interest rates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to ask you to help me find a solution.

I would like to use something like df.groupby('Client') and apply to it custom function that calculates Present Value of all cash flows for each client. The method of calculation PV for different discount rates is mentioned in excel formula on attached image. The problem is that Discount rate and payments aren't constant.

Can you plase help?

Here comes the DataFrame:

```html
pd.DataFrame([
    ['Ann',1,100,0.05],
     ['Ann',2,200,0.06],
     ['Ann',3,100,0.07],
     ['Tamara',1,300,0.05],
     ['Tamara',2,100,0.08],
     ['Tamara',3,200,0.09]],columns=['Client','Period','Payment','Discount rate'])
```

[image: Excel formula shows the process of PV of cash flows caluclation for each client]

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you

Answer (score 0):

```html
def pv_custom_function(x):
discount1 = x['Payment'] / ((x['Discount rate'] + 1).cumprod())
return discount1.sum()
data.groupby('Client').apply(pv_custom_function)
```